# Receding Horizon Vs Finite Horizon in Planning

Tags: optimization, control-theory, operations-research

So, I am reading a paper on [TSP](http://flourish-project.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/2017-iros-popovic.pdf). In one of the papers it is mentioned:

> We plan using a fixed-horizon approach, alternating between replanning and execution until the elapsed time $t$
>   exceeds the budget $B$

However the definition of fixed horizon in this [paper](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~sl2smith/papers/2013TRO-Recharging_in_Persistent_Tasks_final.pdf) research paper is mentioned as follows:

> The fixed horizon approach to path planning involves
>   computing an optimal path over the entire planning horizon

So my question is: If fixed horizon is meant to last over entire planning horizon (which I doubt) then why did the author in the paper above mentioned:

> alternating between replanning and execution:

after mentioning we follow fixed horizon approach? Isnt this receding horizon approach? where you plan again and again after certain time step like in model predictive control?

Comment: If the paper is published, can you supply a link to it (or at least a citation, including where in the paper they refer to a fixed horizon approach)?

Comment: I have also added the link in the question. The statement is mentioned in the 3rd page under "Planning approach"

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a question concerning some paper A that uses "replanning and execution" but you post a link for some other paper B. I also searched paper B for the key words "planning approach" but didn't find anything.

Comment: @Michael, let me double check this and add the reference. Also in general how do we differentiate between receding horizon and finite horizon in planning. Let me check on the reference in the meantime.

Comment: @Michael, I added the paper link. I might have mistakenly removed the link while editing.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER From the new paper you post, the interpretation of prubin below is indeed the correct one: The time interval of interest is $\{0, 1, ..., T\}$ and it never changes.   I read that paragraph on page 3 and they even use the word "refining" which is the same word I used in my comment in support of the prubin answer.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the comment, so once again in receding horizon, is the horizon size fixed or it changes? So even if we keep the horizon size say 20sec as we move towards the 20sec mark the horizon shrinks, so does it mean its fixed or receding? I referred to the papers to provide some context but I want to know the difference in general.

Comment: @Michael I ask this because model predictive control is basically receding horizon control and in there the horizon is fixed. So thats why if shall appreciate a bit comprehension on this.

Comment: I would view "receeding horizon" as a high-level description of an algorithmic structure of "compute in terms of a fixed amount in the future and update-as-you-go."  Many algorithms can be described this way and specifics can vary.  It does not make sense to say "it always means this" or "it always means that."  (Is a vehicle always a red car? Is a vehicle allowed to be a green car or a blue truck?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a reference from Wikipedia article on [MPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_predictive_control#:%7E:text=The%20main%20differences%20between%20MPC,for%20the%20whole%20time%20horizon.), which states:

> The main differences between MPC and LQR are that LQR optimizes in a
> fixed time window (horizon) whereas MPC optimizes in a receding time
> window,[4] and that a new solution is computed often whereas LQR uses
> the single (optimal) solution for the whole time horizon.

So to grab the gist of above, fixed horizon is fixed time interval where plan is executed, and the plan is NOT recomputed until horizon is finished while receding horizon the plan gets repeatedly computed and executed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive (this isn't my area of competence), but I think in the first paper they are planning movement over a fixed spatial domain (which I guess is the "horizon"), and then refining the information or parameters and replanning over the same horizon. So it is not a receding horizon approach.

Comment: If they are replanning, then doesnt it mean it is receding horizon? Isnt Fixed horizon pertains to the plan that is executed over that fixed horizon or period and receding horizon means the plan keeps changing over short time?

Comment: If I understand this correctly (a big "if"), "receding horizon" means the horizon is changing at each iteration, as opposed to replanning over the same horizon at each iteration.

Comment: This answer seems to be the most likely interpretation, given that the first paper (paper A) has not been linked.  Perhaps it is an issue of "online algorithm" versus "offline."  If the algorithm is offline, the "replanning" could indeed just be some numerical method for refining a previous heuristically-generated solution.  So you can go through many "replanning" stages but all of that is a big (offline) "super-plan" for an algorithm that you will eventually implement over a fixed batch of time steps $\{0, 1, ..., T\}$.